# Jenkins + git - ensure that the build has been run

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

Recently I've discussed with our devops the following scenario and I'm not sure what is the best technical way to implement this:

We have a "master" branch and an assigned job Jenkins. Once someone pushes to master the job gets triggered out of git's server hook.

Now we have a lot of feature branches. 
When developer(s) are done with their feature we have an ability to run the same job as master but against their feature branch.

What we would like to do is to automate the flow of pushing to master:

- When Developer finishes the development and makes all the commits into feature branch, he/she merges into the feature branch the latest master so that the feature branch contains now the master changes + developer's changes, done manually and locally + does manual checks that everything works.
- Developers pushes the feature branch to remote feature branch and Triggers the Jenkins Job. Jenkins job should build the feature branch just like it builds master (with integration tests and everything) and provide a "guarantee" that the feature branch is tested and is eligible to be pushed to master.
- Now since the merge back to master is expected to be fast-forward, we would like to automate this if possible so that jenkins would merge it back automatically to master and push. Of course if the master has been changed meanwhile, we should try to merge back the latest changes from the master into the feature branch and rerun the build on feature branch.

The ratio is to avoid pushing to master the code that has not been checked by CI beforehand.

My question is, what is the best way to organize such a flow technically?

Being by myself a java developer I thought about the option of some groovy script that would generate the information about the successful jenkins build on the team branch in some database + server side hook that will check against that db whether its possible to merge changes back into the master branch.

Are there any better tools for that?
Maybe there is some already-implemented solution for such a thing?

Thanks

Comment: Only addresses part of your question, but can you have a script in your Jenkins project that only runs after a successful build, and executes `git checkout master && git merge {branch-name} --ff-only`? If it's only a very rare occurrence that the merge isn't a fast-forward, might it be good enough to do this, and just have Jenkins fail if the merge fails, prompting the developer to merge from master again and repeat the process? Obviously if that's likely to be a more frequent problem, it would be worth spending more time on, but maybe this is a start?

Comment: Yes,. Thanks a lot for comment. I think this is the best thing we can do. I currently also think the same :) Thanks. I still hope, maybe people over here will share their experience/provide some alternative solutions for this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there's a smarter, more elegant solution :) I haven't used it myself, but I know there's a git-flow plugin for Jenkins, which might be worth a look?